# Loading file from server into adapter view flipper

Tags: android

I am new to using android studio adapter flipper view. I successfully retrieved images and videos from server with glide into the adapter view flipper. I made the view change its items at every 10 seconds interval with this line of code:

```
mAdapter.setFlipInterval (1000);
```

I also made it start flipping automatically. But now I have a problem and the problem is that the adapter view flipper starts flipping even before the video has finished loading. I want the flipper to start counting only when the file has loaded from the server:

Here is a little part of the code:

```
public class Flipper extends AppCompactActivity {

    ArrayList <Flip> arrayList ;
    private AdapterViewFlipper mAdapter;

@Override
    ...
//the acivity is created here
    ...
    mAdapter = findViewById(R.id.adapter);
    arrayList = new ArrayList <>();
    startTheFlip ();
    }
public void startTheFlip(){
    StringRequest Sr = new StringRequest (Request.Method.POST, yourUrl, 
new Response.Listener <String>(){
        public void onResponse(response){
            JsonArray array = new JsonArray (response);
            for (int r = 0; r  < array.length; r++){
                JsonObject obj = array.getJsonObject (r);
                arrayList.add (new Flip (
                    obj.getString ("type"),
                    obj.getString ("file")
                ));
            }
        FlipperAdapter adap = new FlipperAdapter ();
        mAdapter.setAdapter (adap);
        mAdapter.setAutoFlipping (true);
        mAdapter.setFlipInterval (1000);
        mAdapter.startFlipping();
        }
    });
}

    private class FlipperAdapter extends BaseAdapter {
        Contex ctx;
        ArrayList <Flip> arrayList;
        Flipper (Contex ctx, ArrayList <Flip> arrayList){
        this.ctx=ctx;
        this.arrayList = arrayList;
    }
        ...
    //Here the methods are implemented
        ...

        LayoutInflater inflater = LayoutInflater.from(ctx);
        View view = inflater.inflate (R.layout.flipper, null);

        ImageView mImage = view.findViewById(R.id.image);
        VideoView mVideo = findViewById (R.id.video);

        //i is an int parameter from one of the methods
        Flip flip = arrayList.get (i);
        if (flip.getType.equals ("image/jpeg")){
            Glide.with (ctx).load (flip.getFile).into (mImage);
        }else if (flip.getType.equals ("video/mp4")){
            mVideo.loadURL (flip.getFile);
            mVideo.start ();
            }
    }
}
```

The Flip class is a class that stores the JSON result from the URL as String Array. Please guys I really need your help.

Comment: You say every 10 seconds but you put mAdapter.setFlipInterval (1000); 
1000 milliseconds = 1 second

Comment: That's was a mistake i did 10000 milliseconds